# Querying 2 different entities with a common parameter to sort them

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, union

I have 2 entities : Events and Cards they both have a `'position'` field and I want to retrieve them all and sort them by position in an array.

So I would get something like:

`array('Card_1 (position 1)', 'Event_3 (position 2)', 'Event 2 (position 3)', 'Card 2 (position 4)')` and so on.

Normally I would use something like a `UNION` in Native SQL, is there a simpler way to do that using Doctrine ?

Comment: hmn doctrine has no union support, but you can execute a raw query

Comment: another solution maybe be to persist a mapped super class that has the field your both entities are extending

Comment: I thought about using a mapped super class but according to Doctrine doc:
"A mapped superclass cannot be an entity, it is not query-able and persistent relationships defined by a mapped superclass must be unidirectional (with an owning side only)."

Comment: sorry i meant  "Single Table Inheritance" you can query those. http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't use a Native Query as it was getting me cardinality issues and using a mapped superclass wasn't an option as this type of class cannot be query-ied.

I retrieved both set of entities separately, merged the array and used usort to do the job:

```
$result = array_merge($events, $cards);
usort($result,  function($a, $b) { return strcmp($a->getPosition(), $b->getPosition()); });
```

If anyone came up with a better solution using Doctrine I am curious to see it.